# Stata r(3900) error

Tags: stata

I have ran a multilevel glm log(link) model on my Mac, and the model didn't converge (didn't provide any technical error messages, just ran for several hours). Then I tried a more powerful Windows computer, however, now I get an error message r(3900):[image]

I know for the fact the the computer is quite powerful. It has several gigabytes of memory. Any suggestions on what is going on?

Comment: I can't really help with the main questions, but have you tried using the `difficult` maximization option in `meglm`? This can help with convergence. Also, sometimes when there are enormous scale differences across the covariates, changing the units to something sensible will help.

Comment: Also, [this FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/windows/large-datasets-and-memory/) may be helpful.

Comment: Hi Dima, thank you for the heads-up. I ran `meglm lny x1 x2 x3 || group_cluster:, link(log) diff`, and it provided me with an error message r(1400): initial values not feasible. The data set is about 800K and has only 1200 group clusters. My regular multilevel OLS runs just fine.

Comment: I would try the advice [here](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/memeglm.pdf#page=19).

Comment: I have tried all suggestions/corrections in that document, and unfortunately, the regression is still not converging. I wonder if the dataset size contributes to that (I have roughly 800K obs.).

Comment: I think contacting Stata tech support is your best bet.

Comment: Haven't thought about that! Thanks Dima!